# Indent output of command (non-blocking) in powershell

Tags: powershell, text-indent

I'm looking for a non-blocking way of indenting the output of a command in powershell, by non-blocking I mean the output of the command must be displayed as the process runs.

`Start-Process` is non-blocking, however I can't figure out how to indent the output.

`& { }` can be indented, however doesn't output anything until the process is finished.

I came across a similar question on here and the provided solution to that question is as follows:

```
$ping = & { ping -n 2 google.com } 2>&1
$ping | ForEach-Object {"    $_"}
```

The above code almost does exactly what I need it to, however it won't output anything until the process is completed.. which will not work for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only blocking step is the variable assignment, so skip that completely and it'll work as expected:

```
& { ping -n 2 google.com } 2>&1 |ForEach-Object {"    $_"}
```

If you still want to capture the raw output from the application and store it in a variable, use `Tee-Object`:

```
& { ping -n 2 google.com } 2>&1 |Tee-Object -Variable ping |ForEach-Object {"    $_"}
```

Comment: So simple.. thank you for taking the time and replying!

Your solution does appears to be working, however I'm experiencing some strange behavior.

I get two lines of output and then no output until the command finishes? All the output is indeed indented.. not sure why this is happening tho.

Edit: Appears the command I'm issuing creates a child process.. I think this may be why. This behavior doesn't appear to be happening with `Start-Process` however.

Comment: @Paul The output timing is due to how `ping.exe` works - it waits 1 second between attempts, so the last batch of output you'll get is the reply line for the last attempt immediately followed by that stats. You'd see the exact same behavior if runing `ping -n 2 ...` without the rest. You can inject extra wait time if you like, with something like `... |ForEach-Object {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500; "    $_"}`

Comment: I'm not using ping, I only posted that as an example.. I'm running a program called esptool (it's a flashing utility). I've observed the child process being created in task manager, it appears all the output from that process isn't displayed until its complete. Then resumes updating the output instantly as expected. Not sure if there is a way around that..